# Como adicionar paginação na pagina search.php no woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

A Paginação não esta funcionando no search.php no site que estou desenvolvendo. Quando peço para mostrar todos os produtos, ele mostra certinho a paginação, porém quando faço uma pesquisa aonde é gerado resultados para varias paginas, ele so me retorna a primeira pagina e nao me da opçao de mudar para proxima pagina, como é mostrado na pagina de todos os produtos.

search.php:
           </h2> -->

```
    woocommerce_product_loop_start();
    woocommerce_product_subcategories();

    while (have_posts()):
        the_post();
        wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');
    endwhile; // end of the loop. 
    woocommerce_product_loop_end();
    /**
     * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
    <?php 

elseif (!woocommerce_product_subcategories(array(
        'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start(false),
        'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end(false)
    ))):
    wc_get_template('loop/no-products-found.php');

endif;
?> </div><!-- /pagina-loja__dir --></div><!-- /row --></div><!-- /container --></div><!-- /pagina-loja --> <?php
get_footer('shop');
?>
```

Comment: Dê mais detalhes sobre o problema

Comment: Alterado o topico, espero que tenho melhorado